# How to describe route with complex parameter in Symfony 2

Tags: regex, symfony, routes

I have route: `/user/username/{username}.{_format}`
And `username` could have any symbols. 
For example, all of the follows will be valid:

- `user`
- `user.name`
- `user.name@example.com`
- `user@example.com`
- `user.name jr`
- `user'o name`

and so on...

each part of `username` could have any characters...

Also `_format` is optional string e.g `json`, `xml` ...

How I can describe it in my routing rules?

At now I have this:

```
MyBundle_getUserByUsername:
    pattern: /user/username/{username}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:User:getUserByUsername, _format: json }
    requirements:
        _method: GET
        username: ".+"
```

But it not so useful as it could be. I can't specify `format` parameter...

I need your help guys...

Answer (score 1):

```
MyBundle_getUserByUsername:
    pattern: /user/username/{username}.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:User:getUserByUsername, _format:json}
    requirements:
        _method: GET
        username: ".+(?<=.)"
```

Comment: It's not Symfony, it's all about regular expression. You just need to define a route to perform the next pattern: "/^\/user\/username\/(.+?)(\.json|html)?$/"

Answer (score 0):

Use the [lazy quantificator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Lazy_quantification)

```
MyBundle_getUserByUsername:
    pattern: /user/username/{username}.{_format}
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:User:getUserByUsername, _format: json }
    requirements:
        username: ".+?"
        _method: GET
        _format: html|json
```

Comment: This won't work if the username is `user.name@example.com` like in the question.

Comment: It works well for me. Show the result route definition. Also, i updated my answer with the complete route definition, check it out, maybe you missed something.